# Aurelia - Navmenu not updating based on @computed value

Tags: typescript, data-binding, dependency-injection, aurelia

I received and answer from [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47122995/5750758) question which I think is correct however I do not get a value propagating back to the view. I have added in a number of console.logs and they are not being hit.

Here is my navMenu - I wanted "loggedIn" to be true if it has a value in localstorage...

```
        <template bindable="router">
        <require from="./navmenu.css"></require>
        <div class="main-nav">
            <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#/home">Jobsledger.API</a>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">

                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                        <li repeat.for="row of router.navigation" class="${ row.isActive ? 'link-active' : '' }">
                            <a href.bind="row.href" if.bind="loggedIn">${ row.title }</a>

                            <a href.bind="row.href" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"
                               if.bind="loggedIn">
                                ${row.title}
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                            </a>

                            <ul if.bind="loggedIn" class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li repeat.for="menu of row.settings.nav">
                                    <a href.bind="menu.href">${menu.title}</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        test ${loggedIn}
    </template>
```

Here is the navmenu.ts viewmodel showing the @computedFrom and the getter:

```
            import { autoinject, inject, NewInstance } from "aurelia-framework";
        import { computedFrom } from "aurelia-binding";
        import { bindable } from "aurelia-templating";

        import { LoggedInService } from "../components/auth/LoggedInService";

        @autoinject
        export class Navmenu {
            constructor(private testAuthentication: LoggedInService) {
                console.log("loggedin value: ", this.testAuthentication.isAuthenticated())
            }

            @computedFrom('testAuthentication.authenticated')
            get loggedIn() {
                console.log("loggedin value: ", this.testAuthentication.isAuthenticated())
                return this.testAuthentication.isAuthenticated()
            }
        }
```

Here is my loggedIn class - pretty simple - goes off and gets a value in local storage - if its not there it returns false.

```
         export class LoggedInService {
          private LOGGED_IN = "loggedIn";
          constructor() {}

          isAuthenticated(): boolean {
            var authenticated = localStorage.getItem(this.LOGGED_IN);

            console.log("LOGGEDIN - typeof: ", authenticated);

            if (authenticated != null) {
              return true;
            } else return false;
          }
        }
```

None of my console.logs are displayed in the console which means none of those functions are being hit.. I dont know why.. should be pretty simple..

Could someone have a look over this and direct me to why its still not working?

**UPDATE**

I appreciate Jeremy taking a look and I have had a go at implementing this. Here are my updated classes.

I have changed the names on the classes but they represent what Jeremy has suggested. Here they are in the same order he presented them...

Here is my version of his "user.ts":

```
        export class LoggedInService {
        private LOGGED_IN = "loggedIn";

        isLoggedIn: boolean = false;
        userName: string = 'anonymous';

        constructor() { }

        isAuthenticated(): boolean {
            var authenticated = localStorage.getItem(this.LOGGED_IN);

            console.log("LOGGEDIN value HERE!: ", authenticated);

            if (authenticated != null) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

I have "isLoggedIn" set as 'false' and "username" set to 'anonymous'.

Here is my version of "navmenu.ts":

```
    import { autoinject } from "aurelia-framework";
    import { bindable } from "aurelia-templating";
    import { LoggedInService } from "../components/auth/LoggedInService";

    @autoinject
    export class Navmenu {

        constructor(public loggedInService: LoggedInService) { }
    }
```

I assume this should give my navmenu.html - the view - access to those values and here I am uncertain how they should be accessed in the if.bind. I just wanted to test it using:

```
 <div if.bind="loggedInService.isLoggedIn">
        working
    </div>
```

this didnt work.

Finally here is my version of auth_service.ts. This is where the fetch is undertaken to login - I have set the value of loggedIn and username in the fetch:

```
    constructor(
    private login: userLogin,
    private loggedinService: LoggedInService,
    private tokenService: TokenService,
    private userService: UserService,
    private router: Router,
    private http: HttpClient,
    private controllerFactory: ValidationControllerFactory
) {
    this.router = router;
    this.controller = controllerFactory.createForCurrentScope();
    this.controller.addRenderer(new BootstrapFormRenderer());


    // Check if user is logged in
    if (this.loggedinService.isAuthenticated()) {
        loggedinService.isLoggedIn = true;
        loggedinService.userName = this.userService.getUserName();
    }
}

submitLogin() {
    if (this.controller.validate()) {
        // Lets do a fetch!

        this.login.Username = this.username;
        this.login.Password = this.password;

        const task = fetch("/api/jwt", {
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify(this.login),
            headers: new Headers({ 'content-type': 'application/json' })
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                // First save the JWT and as well save it to loggedInService.
                this.loggedinService.isLoggedIn = this.tokenService.saveJWT(data);

                // Next go back to the api and get the username and save that to loggedInService also.
                this.loggedinService.userName = this.userService.saveUserName();

                // Finally redirect to home page.
                this.router.navigate("home");
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.tokenService.clearJWT();
            });
    }
}
```

I still dont get any kind of activity in the navmenu view.. not sure if I have set this ok wondering if someone can take another look at this.. maybe I havent referenced it correctly in the navbar view. I note that loggedInService is a dependency both in the navmenu and also the login.ts viewmodels. Shouldnt this work or have screwed something up....

Comment: Shouldn't the computed from attribute be looking at isAuthenticated? Authenticated seems to be a local variable in the isAuthenticated function

Comment: Wondering if you might expand on this. I have changed the @computedFrom('testAuthentication.authenticated') to @computedFrom('testAuthentication.isAuthenticated') and no consol.logs show up..

Comment: As you currently have this constructed, there's no way to keep Aurelia from having to dirty check this. The `computedFrom` won't work here, as you're telling it to look at the result of a function (a function with no parameters, at that) and not at simple properties. You'll need to completely rethink how you're checking if a user is logged in if you want to avoid dirty checking.

Comment: Im at the start of a fairly steep learning curve here.. Ashley has indicated my current approach is flawed... Happy to rethink this.. Could some one suggest how to 1) Avoid dirty checking in this instance and 2) update value in the view based on a change in a local storage variable change..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could model this slightly differently and avoid all the dirty checking and computedFrom stuff.

Create a model for your current user:

*user.ts*

```
export class User {
  isLoggedIn = false;
  name = 'anonymous';
}
```

Then take a dependency on the user in view models that need access to the `isLoggedIn` state or the user's details:

*navmenu.ts*

```
@autoinject
export class Navmenu {
  constructor(public user: User) { }
}
```

Services that do the login work or the local storage work also take a dependency on the current user, updating it's properties when the login state changes.

*auth-service.ts*

```
@autoinject
export class AuthService {
  constructor(private user: User) { 
     if (... check local storage, etc ... ) {
       user.isLoggedIn = true;
       user.name = ....
     }
  }

  login(username, password) {
    return fetch('/api/login', { method: 'POST', body: { ... } })
      .then(result => {
         ... 
         ...
         this.user.isLoggedIn = true;
         this.user.name = username;
         ...
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jeremy for having a look. I have updated the question to reflect you solution. I am still having trouble accessing those variables in the navmenu view...

Comment: I had a second problem underlying this in that the aurelia template I used had custom elements and was importing the navmenu as an html view without the viewmodel. I thus couldnt get any binding to work even though I had the correct dependencies. After a number of questions with this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/47152839/5750758 I finally sorted out the binding problems.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you didnt use your view model at all. Try check if you reference to the module navmenu view model, or its view `navmenu.html`